# Recommendation for home automation solution

Tags: home-automation

I have an buried driveway sensor - the kind with the cable that runs back to the house to a control unit - and I've been using an X10 Universal Module wired up to that and plugged in to communicate to chime units in the home.  We've had this system for nearly 20 years and it has generally worked OK but the X10 modules have been failing and I feel like I'd like to upgrade things.

The existing driveway sensor still works great so I don't see any reason to change that out at this point.  But I'd like to use a newer wireless technology (or I'm also not opposed to something better than X10 for a powerline solution) to accomplish (at least) the same job as my existing setup did.

The driveway sensor system is a Mier Driveway Alert system.  It has Input -- 120 VAC, 50-60Hz, 3.6 WattsOutput -- 24 VDC at 100 Milliamps or: Dry Contact Relay - 24V/1AMP Maximum.

I see a lot of Z-Wave and Zigbee and Thread and other modules out there but have not seen a similar module to the X10 Universal module - something to take the wired signal from the driveway unit convert it into the appropriate wireless setup.  It is very possible I've just overlooked this.

Do you have suggestions for a solution?  I'm mainly interested in a straightforward solution that works.

My sensor unit is about 30' from the house and, ideally, I'd like to be able to put a few chimes around the home and maybe have an option to send an alert to my phone.

Thoughts?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here.

Comment: please provide as much information as you can about the driveway sensor  ..... use the edit button to add the info to your question

Answer (score 1):

Your description of the system mentions a [**Dry Contact Sensor**](https://www.absoluteautomation.com/switchspot-spotprotect-wifi-dry-contact-sensor-with-email-and-sms/). There are several types on the market. Simply wire these into your existing setup as either Normally Open or Normally Closed. They are easy to set up and some come with free wi-fi phone notifications when triggered.

Here is a [**Mier Installation Manual**](https://mierproducts.com/wp-content/uploads/2015-Drive-Alert-DA-500-Manual.pdf) that shows wiring possibilities for NO and NC accessories that can help you along.

[image: Spot Protect Dry Contact Sensor]